# moment.format() returns next day

Tags: fullcalendar, momentjs

So Im using Fullcalendar and on dayClick I'm trying to find events that match the day clicked.

```
 var events = $calendar.fullCalendar('clientEvents');
    if(events.length > 0) {
       for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
          if (date.format('YYYY-MM-DD') == events[i].start.format('YYYY-MM-DD')) {

    ...
```

Now

```
date.format('YYYY-MM-DD')
```

returns the day I clicked but when the for loop gets to that days events then

```
events[i].start.format('YYYY-MM-DD')
```

returns the next day. This seems to be affected by UTC but this applies to ALL days with events. Not just today. I've tried different formats and still the same. Here's something I noticed though:

```
n
_ambigTime:false
_ambigZone:true
_d:Thu Feb 09 2017 08:00:00 GMT-0500 (EST)
_f:"YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"
_fullCalendar:true
_i:"2017-02-08 13:00:00"
_isAMomentObject:true
_isUTC:true
_isValid:true
_locale:f
```

Notice that _d and _i are different. _i is actually the right date/time. So how can I reference that?

Answer (score 1):

All moment properties starting with `_` (like `_d` and `_i`) are for internal use and should not be used.

If you want to check if two moment object represent the same day you can use [`isSame`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-same/) passing the second parameter to limit granularity, instead of comparing formatted strings. In your case:

```
date.isSame(events[i].start, 'day')
```

The problem is that some of your objects are created in UTC mode (`_isUTC: true`), so they will be displayed using UTC time (previous day in some cases) instead of local time.

More info about UTC mode [here](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/):

> By default, moment parses and displays in local time.
>
> If you want to parse or display a moment in UTC, you can use `moment.utc()` instead of moment().
>
> This brings us to an interesting feature of Moment.js. UTC mode.
>
> While in UTC mode, all display methods will display in UTC time instead of local time.